# Not Logging the supplier when suppplier has more then 1 product in his list

Tags: python, django

this project is about supplier and client management system when we login to client it is working perfect but when I log in to supplier it is throwing error... if we add more than one product in supplier list then it's not logging in that account again. only allowing 1 order .

> this is the model of my code.

```
  # models.py
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.db import models
    from django.shortcuts import render, redirect,HttpResponse
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from .models import *
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login,logout
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.contrib import messages
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
    class Client(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    
    class Supplier(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        product_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/')
```

> from here views.py start of start of the code

```
    def signup(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            email = request.POST.get('email')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
            Confirm_Password = request.POST.get('Confirm_Password')
            user_type = request.POST.get('role')
    
            if password != Confirm_Password:
                return HttpResponse("Your password and confirm password are not the same!!")
            
            elif User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                return HttpResponse("Email Already Exist")
            
            # Create the user
            elif user_type == 'client':
                # ... existing code for client registration ...
                mobile = request.POST.get('mobile')
                address = request.POST.get('address')
                user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
                client = Client.objects.create(user=user, mobile=mobile, address=address)
                client.save()
                return redirect('login')
            
            elif user_type == 'supplier':           
                # ... existing code for supplier registration ...
                product_name = request.POST.get('product_name')
                product_price = request.POST.get('product_price')
                image = request.FILES.get('image')            
                user = User.objects.create(username=username, email=email)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save()
                supplier = Supplier.objects.create(user=user, product_name=product_name, product_price=product_price, image=image)
                supplier.save()   
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('supplier_dashboard')
                else:
                    return HttpResponse("Failed to log in the user.")
        
        return render(request, 'enroll/signup.html')
        
        
        
        
    def user_login(request):
        try:
            if request.method == 'POST':
                username = request.POST.get('username')
                password = request.POST.get('password')
                user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    if hasattr(user, 'client'):
                        return redirect('client_dashboard')
                    elif hasattr(user, 'supplier'):
                        messages.success(request, "Welcome Successfully Login")
                        return redirect('supplier_dashboard')
                messages.error(request, "Incorrect Username or Password")
            return render(request, 'login/index.html')
        except Exception as e:
            messages.error(request, "Please Try Login Again")
            return render(request, "login/index.html")
    
    # client dashboard
    def client_dashboard(request):
        supplier=Supplier.objects.all()
        messages.success(request,"Login Succesfull")
        return render(request, 'enroll/client_dashboard.html',{'suppliers':supplier})
        
    
    # supplier dashboard
    @login_required
    def supplier_dashboard(request):
        if request.method=='POST':
            product_name=request.POST.get('product_name')
            product_price=request.POST.get('product_price')
            image=request.FILES.get('image')
            data=Supplier.objects.create(user=request.user,product_name=product_name,product_price=product_price,image=image)
            data.save()
            supplier=Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        else:
            supplier=Supplier.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        return render(request, 'enroll/supplier_dashboard.html',{'suppliers':supplier})
```